# Register dependency per request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Previously I registered dependencies in IoC container at application start setting controller factory. But now I need to register some dependencies per request. Are there any ways to make it in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, even every basic IoC container supports object lifecycle management in some way.

My favorite container is [Ninject 2.0](http://ninject.org/) which seemlessly integrates with ASP.NET MVC 3. It's available as a NuGet package called `Ninject.MVC3`.

In the `RegisterServices(IKernel)` method, you can define a scope for each type to resolve. The following code configures Ninject to return the same single instance of `SomeImplementation` when `ISomeInterface` is being resolved:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ISomeInterface>().To<SomeImplementation>().InRequestScope();
}
```

Ninject lets you choose from one of the following available scopes:

- `InRequestScope()`
- `InThreadScope()`
- `InSingletonScope()`
- `InTransientScope()`

Nate Kohari wrote a blog post about that topic called [Cache-and-Collect Lifecycle Management in Ninject 2.0](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/) — you would definitely want to check that out!